# XMLHttpRequest cannot load response

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am getting this error when I try to consume a response from an api. I am calling to the api from my local machine.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.theurl.com/api/getstuff?json={%22P…22100%22,%22%22:%22100%22},%22$$hashKey%22:%22object:32%22}]}. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

According to the server admin, **cors has been enabled**, and I am able to past the full url and json to the getStuff api through a browser and see the response. So I am trying to identify other possible reasons for this issue.

in my **api.service.js** file I have this...

```
this.getStuff = function (attributes) {
    return $http.get('http://www.theurl.com/api/getstuff?json=' + JSON.stringify(attributes)).
        success(function(){
        });
};
```

I call the getStuff function from my **getStuff.js** file like this...

```
  $scope.getTheStuff = function (){
         Services.getStuff($scope.Attributes)
         .then(function (res) {
                //$scope.selectedStuff = res
         })
         .finally(function () {

         });
    };
```

Any ideas whats going wrong? thanks

Comment: An HTTP 405 error is Method Not Allowed, The resource you're trying to hit does not accept the POST method

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but I am using $http.get, or does that make a difference?

Comment: then not accept the GETmethod

Comment: So you are saying that the server does not accept the get method. Thanks. So the server guys needs to fix this

Comment: u could  request  wrong Get ,maybe ,check your get request and properlly asigned.like headers:'Content-Type'.Take a look at here more info http://tedshd.logdown.com/posts/202391-angularjs-http